# python tkInter browse folder button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to make a browse folder button using tkinter and to store the path into a variable. So far i am able to print the path but i am not able to store it in a variable. Can you please advise?

Below i attach the code that i use.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

def browse_button():
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print(filename)
    return filename


root = Tk()
v = StringVar()
button2 = Button(text="Browse", command=browse_button).grid(row=0, column=3)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You have stored it in a variable. It is stored in `filename`. If you wish to store for other functions to use, then you should use a. Classes b. Global variables. I'll provide an example of a Global variable below.

Comment: great! Using global variable it worked! thanks!!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is an example of storing the directory path as a global variable and using that to populate a Label.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

def browse_button():
    # Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var
    # called folder_path
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder_path.set(filename)
    print(filename)


root = Tk()
folder_path = StringVar()
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=folder_path)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
button2 = Button(text="Browse", command=browse_button)
button2.grid(row=0, column=3)

mainloop()
```